# Word to combine brother-in-law and sister-in-law?

Tags: possessives, plural-forms

Imagine the following scenario:

Ronald and Alana are a couple.

Jono and Daisy are a couple.

Jono is Alana's brother.

What would be the correct way to say the following phrase?

> We are Ronald and Alana, Daisy's **brothers-in-law**.

> We are Ronald and Alana, Daisy's **siblings-in-law**.

> We are Ronald and Alana, Daisy's **brother/sister-in-law**.

Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are Ronald and Alana, `Daisy's brother- and sister-in-law`. would be most usual. Note hanging hyphen attached to 'brother'. We are Ronald and Alana, `Daisy's siblings-in-law` is possible but unusually formal.